# I am unable to access 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin in web browser

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using Fedora 20 with apache 2.4.9, php 5.5.11, and mysql 5.16.17 running. Unfortunately, I am unable to access phpmyadmin. I have tried adding the extension=mysqli.so and also for mbstring in /etc/php.ini, did not work even after I restarted apache. I then used yum install php-mysqli and php-mbstring...after a successful installation, didn't work. I look at the php.info and I don't see a mysqli or mbstring installed. I have been researching...and I can not find any clue how to fix this. The output for 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/ shows this:

Index of /phpmyadmin

```
Parent Directory
.coveralls.yml
CONTRIBUTING.md
ChangeLog
LICENSE
README
RELEASE-DATE-4.1.12
browse_foreigners.php
changelog.php
chk_rel.php
composer.json
config.sample.inc.php
config/
db_create.php
db_datadict.php
db_events.php
db_export.php
db_import.php
db_operations.php
db_printview.php
db_qbe.php
db_routines.php
db_search.php
db_sql.php
db_structure.php
db_tracking.php
db_triggers.php
doc/
error_report.php
examples/
export.php
favicon.ico
file_echo.php
gis_data_editor.php
import.php
import_status.php
index.php
js/
libraries/
license.php
navigation.php
phpinfo.php
phpmyadmin.css.php
phpunit.xml.nocoverage
pmd_display_field.php
pmd_general.php
pmd_pdf.php
pmd_relation_new.php
pmd_relation_upd.php
pmd_save_pos.php
prefs_forms.php
prefs_manage.php
print.css
querywindow.php
robots.txt
schema_edit.php
schema_export.php
server_binlog.php
server_collations.php
server_databases.php
server_engines.php
server_export.php
server_import.php
server_plugins.php
server_privileges.php
server_replication.php
server_sql.php
server_status.php
server_status_advisor.php
server_status_monitor.php
server_status_queries.php
server_status_variables.php
server_user_groups.php
server_variables.php
setup/
show_config_errors.php
sql.php
tbl_addfield.php
tbl_change.php
tbl_chart.php
tbl_create.php
tbl_export.php
tbl_find_replace.php
tbl_get_field.php
tbl_gis_visualization.php
tbl_import.php
tbl_indexes.php
tbl_move_copy.php
tbl_operations.php
tbl_printview.php
tbl_relation.php
tbl_replace.php
tbl_row_action.php
tbl_select.php
tbl_sql.php
tbl_structure.php
tbl_tracking.php
tbl_triggers.php
tbl_zoom_select.php
themes.php
themes/
transformation_overview.php
transformation_wrapper.php
url.php
user_password.php
version_check.php
view_create.php
view_operations.php
webapp.php
```

Any suggestions as to why the output of phpmyadmin shows this?

Comment: Yes. When I do a 127.0.0.1/test.php it shows the php stuff.

Comment: SELinux is enforcing ???

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/index.php`. I suspect that will work, in which case the DirectoryIndex wasn't configured for PHP files when you installed PHP.

[DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) is an Apache configuration directive that tells Apache which file names to load (and in which order) when a directory is requested. So if http://example.com/ is loaded and the DirectoryIndex line contains index.html home.html, Apache will first try to load index.html, if that's missing it will try home.html, and if that's missing, it will (depending on the [configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings)), simply show a directory listing. That's what you seem to be seeing here.

So the correct fix is likely to add index.php to your DirectoryIndex directive. It probably looks something like `DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm home.html` and you can simply add `index.php` before or after the other lines (resulting in  something like `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm home.html` instead). Note that this is just an example, I suggest you simply edit your existing line rather than copying and pasting mine.